# Angular get "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html" error on load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, progressive-web-apps

I added PWA to my angular app and after that, I made an error. When I open the site in browser it's work correctly, but after closing the tab and reopening it, I have an error on the console that says "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html".

With this error, my site couldn't load and I have a white page.

The interesting thing is that when I load with (ctrl+f5), the site works correctly again.

** My site work in root and I don't have base href

[image]

Comment: That sounds very much like it was nothing but a caching issue. Does the problem persist, if you test this in a private browser window ...?

Comment: Yes, it's about cashing. When I open a site in browsers private mode, the site works correctly and the site cash some files in the browser. The problem occurred for the second time